# How to run a cluster on data that is strings only R

Tags: r, string, cluster-analysis, unsupervised-learning

I am trying to run a cluster on a very large data set. It contains only strings for values. I have removed the NA's and relaced with a dummy value. My K-Means in R keeps failing due to NA coerecion. How would the community run a cluster on this data. I am shwoing 10 rows of a dummy example below. In this situation lets call the data frame: cluster_data
[image]

ANy help would be greatly appreciated. I am trying see if any of the columns cause the data to break earlier then another to try and understand a possible struture. Thought Clustering with K-means was best approach but do not see how to do with strings. Have converted to factors in R and still have issues. ANy example code is greatly appreciated

Comment: Please don't post your data as a screenshot.

Comment: create a data frame with dummy variables for the categorical variables, and then  use the Jaccard distance (implemented as `dist(method="binary")`)

Answer (score 1):

Question: how do you run kmeans clustering with strings?

Answer: You can't run k means cluster analysis on categorical data. You need data that a distance function can make sense of.

Comment: A distance function is *not* sufficient for k-means. It needs continuous variables where the *mean* is optimal. That pretty much only allows squared Euclidean distance (and a few other Bergman divergences) for k-means.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse agreed, but it's necessary. I thought that was the simplest way to make my point.

Answer (score 1):

K-means is *designed* for continuous variables, where least-squares and the *mean* make sense to be used as centers.

For other data types, it is better to sue other algorithms, such as PAM, HAC, DBSCAN, OPTICS, ...